# Redux, toggling state does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, styled-components

I want to wiggle my search icon when I call this reducer.

```
searchWiggle: (search) => {
  if (search.wiggle) {
    search.wiggle = false;
    search.wiggle = true;
  } else {
    search.wiggle = true;
  }
},
```

However it only works the first time I call the reducer.

When its state is set to `true` the animation plays. But I am guessing Redux is updating very fast and so the animation doesn't play.

How can I accomplish this kind of toggle?

I've tried adding a timeout, but that only results in an error:

```
searchWiggle: (search) => {
  if (search.wiggle) {
    search.wiggle = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      search.wiggle = true;
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    search.wiggle = true;
  }
},
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked`

---

The animation plays like this (with Styled Components):

```
 <IconSearch className={!this.props.wiggle ? "" : "a"}></IconSearch>
```

The animation (the wiggle) only plays one time.

```
const IconSearch = styled.span`
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.sidebar.search.box.icon};
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-family: "${({ theme }) => theme.font.icon}";
  font-weight: 700;
  &::before {
    content: "\f002";
  }
  &.a {
    animation: wiggle 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
  }
`;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a Redux reducer to me. A reducer takes a state object, and returns a **new** state object. This "reducer" takes a state object and mutates it, returning nothing. When you do this, all sorts of bad stuff will happen. A reducer should never modify the state, nor any of the parameters that it is passed.

Comment: @spender I am using slices.

Comment: In my opinion you should keep this in your component state and out of redux.  But if you do it in redux, you want separate actions for starting and ending a wiggle.  The component that dispatches the action can use setTimeout to dispatch the second action.

Comment: It needs to be elevated out of the local component because multiple actions will affect it. I ended up going with something like this: `this.props.dispatch(searchWiggle(false));
        setTimeout(() => this.props.dispatch(searchWiggle(true)), 1);`

Answer (score 0):

instead of true/false, set it to a random value, for example a date.

```
search.wiggle = new Date()
```

If you want to off it

```
search.wiggle = null
```

Then wiggle `if (search.wiggle !== null)`

Comment: Do I set to false before setting the timestamp?

Comment: you don't have to, when the date change, your state change (if your redux is set up properly)

Comment: Right, so first set to null then the timestamp?

Comment: My animation plays like this: `<IconSearch className={!this.props.wiggle ? "" : "a"}></IconSearch>`

Comment: when you change the timestamp, it will rerender. Why do u want to set it to null;

Comment: Only wiggles the first time. It's a one time play animation.